# How to debug a C++ program from PHP?

Tags: php, c++, debugging

I would like to debug a C++ program called from PHP code. I think It should be possible using "gdb", but I don't know exactly how to do that.

my idea is something like that:

```
exec("gdb myprogram");
exec("break 55");
exec("run");
```

but It doesn't work, any suggestion?

Comment: why you need to do that this way ? there are many other ways to do this ...

Comment: php `exec` function will wait until gdb ends. You need a redirected stdin/stdout fd.... Try using `proc_open` or a `expect` scripts.

Comment: How could I do that? what other way? 
This PHP code has to be my API and It has to call the core of the system (writed in C++). I just need to know what is going on when I call It from the API.

Comment: Can't you simply run the C++ program as a stand alone? Then you simply could debug it with `gdb ./myprogram`.

Comment: Write a test case. Let your php run in some mode, in which it only prepares data for c++ app to process. Then run app separately using gdb.